# how to display books of selected category in the sidebar in WordPress without any plugin?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

how to display books of selected category in the sidebar in WordPress without any plugin.

I want to display books in sidebar(Web Page) whose category is activated from the widget(Admin) through checkbox or something like that.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @cabrerahector I don't know anything what to do

Comment: If you don't want to use a plugin then you'll need to code the widget yourself. This should help you get started: [Developing WordPress Widgets](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/widgets/#developing-widgets).

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'book',          // name of post type.
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'Book1',   // taxonomy name
            'field' => 'term_id',           // term_id, slug or name
            'terms' => 1,                  // term id, term slug or term name
        )
    )
) );

while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    // do stuff here....
endwhile;

/**
 * reset the orignal query
 * we should use this to reset wp_query
 */
wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: not working and also I m not able to know what to do

Comment: Provide me detail instructions with screenshot or site url so i can help you

Comment: go to this link i have uploaded same question in detail https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59488755/how-to-retrieve-postsbooks-based-on-categorytaxonomy-in-wordpress